# Github Actions Failed: No jobs defined in `jobs`

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to use GitHub Actions for deployent but I get the error message "No jobs defined in jobs". However, I defined jobs... How can I fix this? The OS is macOS Big Sur 11.4

```
name: Firebase Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Build & Deployment
    runs-on: macos-11

    steps:
      - name: get the source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: install node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "14"

      - name: install node packages
        run: npm i

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
        env:
          CI: false

      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN}}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources) about ***Supported runners and hardware resources***:

> Note: The macOS 11 virtual environment is currently provided as a
> private preview only. Any users or organizations that are already
> using this runner can continue using it, but we're not accepting any
> further users or organizations at this time. The macos-latest YAML
> workflow label still uses the macOS 10.15 virtual environment.